# React Native Redux Actions function problem

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to connect my login screen with redux but I am getting error below while trying to connect with actions.

```
...
<Button
    onPress={() => _signInAsync()}
    title={_LANG.btnLogin}
    color="#3897f1"
/>
....
```

When I press on _SignInAsync => method below;

```
const _signInAsync = () => {
    console.log('HERE')
    saveUserToken()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('HERE')
        navigation.navigate('App');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ 'err': error })
    })
};
```

Once I press Console.log writes successfully but then I get the error ;

```
    TypeError: (0, _actions.saveUserToken().then is not a function (In '(0,_actions.saveUserToken)().then(function () ..._actions.saveUserToken)' is undefined
```

Action;

```
export const saveUserToken = (data) => dispatch => 
    AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc')
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('dispatchec',data)
        dispatch(loading(false));
        dispatch(saveToken('token saved'));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(loading(false));
        dispatch(error(err.message || 'ERROR'));
    })
```

Can you tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: you cannot call `saveUserToken` that way: `saveUserToken()`. it expects `data` and returns a callback which you need to call as well.

Comment: how do you import saveUserToken. also do you dispatch it using mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I use this ; 
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  token: state.token,
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  saveUserToken: () => dispatch(saveUserToken()),
});

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);

Comment: are you using `saveUserToken` from props then inside the component?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I inserted like this =>  ' import { saveUserToken } from '../../redux/actions'; '

Comment: You should use it like `props.saveUserToken().then` signInAsync function